# How to access specific div child of certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my div i have a child div of class "someClass". I want to access that child by classname, not id.

EDIT: Only in this particular div, not all the other divs with same classname

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var childOfNamedDiv = $('#namedDiv>.someClass')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = $('.someClass');
```

See [jQuery Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Answer (score 1):

just use the class selector:

```
$('div>.someClass').toggle()
```

Answer (score 1):

if you already have a reference to the jquery object that is the parent of the div that you want to find:

```
var parent = $("#someDiv"); // this is the div that you may alread have found earlier
var child = parent.children(".someClass");
```